# If Condition Always returning true spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I am writing an aggregation query using spring data to project whether the activity is successful.

The activity is successful if it is not of type `CONNECTIVITY_CHECK` and its status equals `SUCCESS`.

This is the code which I have written to create the project stage.

```
  private ProjectionOperation getProjection() {
    CriteriaDefinition successFulActivityCriteria = getCriteriaForSuccessFulNonHearbeatActivity();
    return Aggregation.project()
        .and(ConditionalOperators.when(successFulActivityCriteria).then(1).otherwise(0))
        .as(isSuccessfulActivityField);
  }

  private Criteria getCriteriaForSuccessFulNonHearbeatActivity() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.and(ActivityHistoryEntityKeys.type)
        .ne(CONNECTIVITY_CHECK.toString())
        .and(ActivityHistoryEntityKeys.activityStatus)
        .is(SUCCESS.toString());
    return criteria;
  }
```

This code creates the following MongoDB query

```
db.getCollection('entityActivity').aggregate([
     { 
         "$project" : { 
         "isSuccessfulActivity" : { "$cond" : { "if" : [{ "$ne" : ["$type", "CONNECTIVITY_CHECK"]}, { "$eq" : ["$activityStatus", "SUCCESS"]}], "then" : 1, "else" : 0}}
     }
])
```

The problem I am facing is that this query always returns 1, even when the type is `CONNECTIVITY_CHECK`

The Mongo DB Record:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f92caaab3823704a346766b"),
    "accountIdentifier" : "accountIdentifier",
    "type" : "ENTITY_USAGE", //other value is `CONNECTIVITY_CHECK`
    "activityStatus" : "SUCCESS",
}
```

I need help in understanding what could have been the issue in the java code (`ConditionalOperators.when`) such that it is generating this if statement which is always true ?.

Also, the statement is of the form `if: []`. I haven't seen any if statement in any docs which takes a list. Please guide me on what I am doing wrong.

PS: Looking at the problem it may seem that it can be solved using a find query but this is a smaller part of a problem I am solving. I will be using the `isSuccessfulActivityField` in the next group statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this -

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "isSuccessfulActivity": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $and: [
              {
                "$ne": [
                  "$type",
                  "CONNECTIVITY_CHECK"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$activityStatus",
                  "SUCCESS"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DC7iu2_Zo90)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the if condition takes a Boolean operation, but the way the code was written it was getting a list of Boolean operators. I suppose it also means something in the MongoDB world, that's why no error was returned.

The MongoDB query given by @wak786 solves the issue.

Here I adding the spring data code:

```
  private ProjectionOperation getProjection() {
    And successFulActivityCriteria = getCriteriaForSuccessFulNonHearbeatActivity();
    return Aggregation.project()
        .and(ConditionalOperators.when(successFulActivityCriteria).then(1).otherwise(0))
        .as(isSuccessfulActivityField);
  }
```

```
  private And getCriteriaForSuccessFulNonHearbeatActivity() {
    return And.and(
        ComparisonOperators.valueOf(ActivityHistoryEntityKeys.type).notEqualToValue(CONNECTIVITY_CHECK.toString()),
        ComparisonOperators.valueOf(ActivityHistoryEntityKeys.activityStatus).equalToValue(SUCCESS.toString()));
  }
```